# Author's automatic association with violation does not work properly on SonarQube 6.7

Tags: java, svn, sonarqube, sonarlint

I'm using Sonarqube 6.7 with the Sonarlint 4 plugin in connected mode with my instance on SonarQube.
When a developer commits his code and Sonar detects a violation, it does not automatically associate the violation with the person who committed the code, I must go through each violation and assign it to the developer.

Here is a screenshot : 
[image]

I respected what is written on the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE67/Automatic+Issue+Assignment) but I do not know exactly where the problem comes from.

Here is  the config of sonar :

```
sonar.host.url=http://host/sonar
sonar.projectName=myproject
sonar.projectKey= myKey
sonar.projectVersion=v0
sonar.sources=.
sonar.java.binaries=**/target/*
sonar.exclusions=**/*.class,**/*.project,**/target/**,**/*.log,**/*.jar,**/*.png,**/*.jpg,**/*.jpeg,**/.sonar/**,sonar-project.properties,**/*.ts, **/*.css
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.java.source=1.7
sonar.java.target=1.7
sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx1024m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -   Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
sonar.scm.provider=svn
sonar.links.scm=https://host/svnroot/project/trunk
sonar.verbose=true
```

Is there a way to do this job automatically after the scan ?

PS : I use SVN for versioning.

Comment: How do you know whom to assign the issues to?

Comment: For the moment, if I neither know to whom I should assign the issues nor the owner of the commit I juste do it by intuition, but I don't know if it's the right thing to do !

Comment: How did you execute the scanner? What is the configuration (all `sonar.` properties)?

Comment: I have a Jenkins job that allows to launch a build and sonar analysis with sonnar-runner, I will update my question with the sonar's config file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issues are auto assigned based on the information provided by the SCM (SVN in your case).

It compares the SCM account with:

- SCM accounts added to each SonarQube user
- SonarQube user login
- SonarQube user email

So the first step is to see if there is information provided by the SCM. You can check this by looking at the code where the issue is (in SonarQube) and see if there is SCM information on the left, next to the line number:

[image]

You can click on it to see the details.

If that is OK, make sure that the SCM account matches some data from a SonarQube user as explained above.

Comment: I can't find the information provided by SVN (picture in my question at the top). The SCM and Sonar credentials are well configured but I can't link commits to violations (picture in my question at the top). Should I add specific config in my sonar config file ?

Comment: I didn't see a picture about the SCM information. I've added a screenshot as an example where you can find it when browsing the code or issues in SonarQube.

Comment: I don't have the SCM data to the left of the line. Possible that I forgot a config on my project. In the sonar's config file I add just `sonar.scm.provider=svn`, is that enough?

Comment: It should work out of the box. The SVN scm plugin needs to be installed in SonarQube (it is by default) and it usually automatically detects that the project is using SVN. Try running the analysis with debug logs enabled. You should see some logs about automatic detection and if it works, about the plugin collecting blame information.

Comment: @Meneses you are right, I don't have SVN plugin in my instance. Thanks for you help